# Mongodb query to get value of nested document specific filed with c#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Below is the sample Bson document which is unstructured. As I am new to MongoDB try to learn building queries.
{

```
       "_id":ObjectId("562e7c594c12942f08fe4192"),
       "shapes":[  
          {  
             "shape":"square",
             "color":"blue"
          },
          {  
             "shape":"circle",
             "color":"red"
          }
       ]
    },
    {  
       "_id":ObjectId("562e7c594c12942f08fe4193"),
       "shapes":[  
          {  
             "shape":"square",
             "color":"black"
          },
          {  
             "shape":
                    {
                        "shape_s_time":""2020-06-29T12:00:14.3716902Z"
                         "shape__time":""2020-06-29T12:00:16.3716902Z"
                     },

             "color":"green"
          }
       ]
    }
```

I have tried this code

```
var collection= db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Test");
var result = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Project(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("shapes.shape.shape_s_time")).ToList();
```

but it giving error as
[image]

Could someone tell how to get values?

Answer (score 0):

you have problems with data. The two above document examples works without any issues. It looks like some of your documents here `shapes.shape.shape_s_time` have different format